# Ajaxify not working?

Tags: jquery

So I have the latest jQuery loaded. I've loaded Ajaxify. I gave the links the class of ajaxify and a target, but nothing happens?? I just don't know where to look anymore. Any suggestions? [Here's the link with source](http://www.heinesiebrand.nl/demo/).

Is it maybe because of Wordpress?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Ajaxify code seems bugged, the error given in my case is

```
'Error: Your jQuery version is old. Version 1.2.6 or newer is required.'
```

because you have version 1.6.1 and the test of the version is

```
if(ver[0] < 1 || ver[1] < 2 || ver[2] < 6){
//returns error 
}
```

try to modify ajaxify.js in that line using something like this

```
if(parseInt(ver[0] + ver[1] + ver[2]) < 126){
//returns error 
}
```

EDIT :

more infos available here

**How to make ajaxify compatible with jquery v1.3.0 and higher?**

http://max.jsrhost.com/2008/12/12/ajaxify-support-v20/

Comment: Thanks, but then i get `jQuery(this).ajaxifyAnalyse is not a function
 jQuery(this).ajaxifyAnalyse(current); ` I have included jQuery differently and now i have 1.3.2 loaded, but it still didn't do anything :(

Comment: I didn't tested the solution (but seems to be ok to me), look the link on the edit, if you want you can comment that test for the right version and get it easily done

Comment: Thanks! It doesnt work that well yet, but at least it's doing something :)

Comment: no prob ;) glad it worked... don't forget to mark the solution!

Answer (score 1):

I'm MaX (Ajaxify Programmer)

This bug is very old and it has been solved long time ago. You can find the solution at the top of the support page on my website.

Its good to see some people still using my plugin after this all time :)

Comment: Yeah, nice plugin :) Although when following your set-up instructions, it didn't work. When I removed the class 'ajaxify' from all my <a> tags, it worked. Is there something I'm doing wrong or was that also a bug?